# Derivatives of the multivariate normal CDF w.r.t. its parameters

Tags: normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, multivariate-normal-distribution, derivative, calculus

Let $\boldsymbol X \sim \mathcal N_d(\boldsymbol\mu, \boldsymbol\Sigma)$ and let $f_{\boldsymbol X}(\boldsymbol x)$ be its PDF. The CDF is
$$ F_{\boldsymbol X}(\boldsymbol q) = \int_{-\infty}^{q_1} \dots \int_{-\infty}^{q_d} f_{\boldsymbol X}(\boldsymbol x)\ dx_d \dots dx_1. $$
How do I compute $\partial F_{\boldsymbol X}(\boldsymbol q) / \partial\boldsymbol\mu$ and $\partial F_{\boldsymbol X}(\boldsymbol q) / \partial\boldsymbol\Sigma$? I know the derivatives of the PDF, but I am unsure about the integrals. Can I apply some chain rule?

Comment: Under certain conditions (for example, Fubini's theorem), you can interchange the order of integration and differentiation.  That should get you started...

Comment: If I wanted to differentiate w.r.t. $\boldsymbol x$, Fubini would certainly help, but how can I use Fubini with $\boldsymbol\mu$ or $\boldsymbol\Sigma$? Could you say a few more words, @jbowman?

Comment: Well, less indirectly, it's a special case of Leibniz' rule, and Fubini is used in a proof of it.  Sorry about the imprecision.  The point is that you can just interchange the order of integration and differentiation.